# Is it ok to say "My wife/husband looks like she/he is in a funeral" to express a person who is unhappy about their marriage?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A couple is not getting on well with each other over several issues.

For example, the wife feels sad/unhappy because of financial troubles.

The husband feels sad/unhappy because the house is neglected and he feels the pressure is all on him.

Is it ok to say "**My wife/husband looks like she/he is in a funeral**" (translated from Vietnamese)?

**What is the word that expresses a person (a wife or a husband) who is sad or unhappy "all the time" because she/he is not happy with their life?**

**Note**: Someone says "**long face**" which is, I think, pretty closed to the Vietnamese expression "**her face looks like in a funeral**".

For example, **I am tired of looking at his/her long face all the time**

or

**My wife/husband wears a long face all the time.**

Comment: Those examples make my teeth itch. Welcome to the 1970s.

Comment: Please edit to narrow the request. There are millions of ways to say that someone is unhappy, even habitually unhappy. If you want to ask specifically about "is '___ looks like they're in a funeral'", that's much easier. It's not really a common idiom, but it's readily understood, and comparing situations to funerals is common enough in English ("I'm the kinda guy who laughs at a funeral").

Comment: I've downvoted just for the sexism "wants more money to buy unnecessary things/leaves the house dirty"

Comment: I'd go for '**abject**' "Her life was abject misery because of the outmoded attitudes of her husband" rings well for me.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. You know, re make my teeth itch. I said a similar thing (make my teeth hurt) in the French forum and they chased me out of town. People get so exercised by unusual metaphors. Anyway, why must any of this apply only to man and wife?

Comment: I suggest you put "unhappy" and synonym in google.

Comment: If anyone is sad, upset, depressed, frequently in a bad mood, or cries nearly everyday, the reason is *never* "trivial". Telling someone that their feelings of sadness and dissatisfaction are trivial is hurtful, insensitive, and, ultimately, counterproductive. That person is only going to feel worse because their spouse refuses to listen and/or take responsibility–this works both ways.

Comment: The edited examples are actually no better than the originals; they're still playing the blame game. They've moved from the 70s all the way up to the 80s. The entire question needs heavily re-casting, or dropping in the bin. Sorry.

Comment: If we hammer at the question long enough, then the answer will be… "depression", but by the time we get there, the OP's original intent will have been beaten right out of it :\

Comment: Although they're unpalatable, the Honeymooners/Flintstones marital dynamics examples are not actually integral to the question, and I hope we can avoid reacting to context over content. However, Tom, I don't think the *content* is clear enough yet. Answers include "Why the long face," "he's down in the dumps," "she's blue"—as I said, millions of ways, ranging from clinical and caring to flippant. @Mari-LouA I worry that, by removing "trivial," we lost the one hint that point the way to a question narrow enough to answer. But Tom, the best person to refine your meaning is you.

Comment: Also, I'd hope it's possible here to ask even about repellent concepts. The outlook and concepts underlying a phrase may be unpleasant, but there are still words for it, and it can be worthwhile to understand them.

Comment: @AndyBonner - absolutely, but the answer 'my wife is a miserable sloven', or a 'mardy bum' is not going to go down well either. The initial trivialisation/sexism of the examples will grant an equally odious 'correct answer'. This is not the same as when recently, we were discussing 'how bad is swear word xyz?'.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. My take was that, even if gender roles are removed, the request was specifically for an expression that inherently dismisses or demeans another's sadness, suggesting that they're "making a mountain out of a molehill." As Mari-Lou points out, that's fairly emotionally abusive, but it doesn't mean that Tom's asking for his own use; the "scene-setting" suggested to me that maybe he's trying to write dialogue for an insensitive lout. At any rate, it will still need some focusing to be answerable...

Comment: @AndyBonner, I think "wear a long face" is pretty closed to the Vietnamese expression "her/his face looks like in a funeral".

Comment: In general, we say that someone looks like they are **at** a funeral, if they look unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the one word that sums-up the move from happiness to unhappiness is **disenchanted**.  What was supposed to be good isn't any longer.

Comment: **Trapped** is another way to put it, especially when referring to married couples.  What was never good is now understood to be immutable and terminal.

Comment: Do you have a more friendly word like "a long face", for example?

Comment: You appear to be trying to describe **looks** rather than **condition/situation**.  When speaking generally in English we tend to describe the situation.  (In literature there's a thing, 'show don't tell', where we might take some sentences to describe activities, expressions and demeanor.  That isn't a one-phrase thing.)